# string.Concat works differently on .net 3.5 and .net 4+

Tags: c#

```
string.Concat(new[] { 'a', 'b', 'c' });
```

returns `"abc"` on **.net 4+**, while returns `"System.Char[]"` on **.net 3.5**

Is there a bug here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that in .NET 4, they added the [`String.Concat<T> Method (IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991828(v=vs.110).aspx) overload to the class.

Prior to .NET 4, passing a value-type array to `string.Concat()` causes the array to be interpret as a simple object. The `Concat()` method calls `ToString()` on it, and viola, you get `System.Char[]`.

From .NET 4 on, any `IEnumerable<T>` passed to the method which doesn't match any of the other overloads gets the new overload. Each element in the `IEnumerable<T>` (an `IEnumerable<char>` in this case) gets `ToString()` called on it, and each of those new `string` values are concatenated.